# How to style layers with SLD in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

It seems like not long ago in `OL2` there was a nice way to style layers with `SLD` and it seems like now it is not possible to do the similar thing in `OL3`. At least, I could not find any example on the web and in official `OL3` documentation I could not find even a single reference to `SLD`. So, why is that and how people in real world applications store/save styles if `SLD` format is not supported any more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SLD [is not yet supported by OpenLayers 3](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2954). I am currently working on OpenLayers 3 support for the mapbox-gl-style spec: [ol-mapbox-gl-style](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-gl-style). It is a small separate library.

There might already be an SLD to mapbox-gl-style converter. If there isn't by the time I'm done, there should be enough funding left to also work on an SLD converter.

Credit goes to [Boundless](http://boundlessgeo.com) and their customers for funding this effort.

Comment: Yes indeed: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-gl-style and https://github.com/Norkart/SLDexit.