# Convert mapbox-style to openlayers 3 vectorTile style

Tags: javascript, mapbox, openlayers-3

I'm using a vectorTile source in openlayers 3 to display a nice vectorized map (basically this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.0/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles-advanced.html))

Now I want to use a different style that I created in mapbox studio (basically the mapbox Outdoors Style with minimal adaptations for my use case), which requires me to write a complete new style for openlayers.

I figured out that I can download a .json file which is like a mapbox config file for my style and follows the mapbox style specification. I heard that there is some development by boundless going on to write a converter which converts this json to a openlayers 3 style. (see this comment on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845793/4901110) ).

Do you know if there is a chance to get this converter somewhere? Or is there a different approach to automatically embed a mapbox style in an openlayers vector layer without rewriting a style function by hand?

Comment: IMHO, it's almost impossible to create such converter. There are too different concepts of styles in MapBox and OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time I found a converter module written by boundless. As it seems it's still in active development, but it already looks promising.

It can be found here: 
[ol-mapbox-style](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).